# Confusing Review Invitation (red dot)

Tags: bug

I got "yellow card" from StackOverflow with message "Your review on triage/### wasn't helpful".

I do not complain about it.

Purpose of this post is to fill the bug.

The problem is that I knew about getting yellow card wrong way.
I became aware of it only when I manually directed browser to review queues page https://stackoverflow.com/review .

StackOverflow usually invites you to participate in review by displaying red dot on review queues icon.
In my case I saw red dot and when I pressed review queues icon I saw message "There are no review queues available to you" (without any clickable URLs).
Well, it could be that queue got cleared before I clicked icon or some glitch.

But when I saw it appear again and again with the same message and without any URLs I wondered what could be the case and visited reviews page by directly specifying URL in browser.

Red dot disappeared once I visited review page and saw the warning so it is OK.

The problem is that red dot appears with no actionable URLs or explanation so user has no chances to know that something strange happens.

It would be nice to add some clickable item under message "There are no review queues available to you" or make this message clickable so user could see what is going on.

Comment: To clarify, the review light (the red dot) indicates that reviews *are available*, not necessarily that you *can review*. For example, as of this moment, tag wiki reviews are available on Meta.SE, but I cannot view them as I don't have the privilege. The red dot is on for me, but clicking it takes me to the "This queue has been cleared!" message.

Comment: It's been [requested before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351386/make-it-more-obvious-that-youre-review-banned) on Meta.SO that review bans are more direct about what happened to you, why you were banned, and for how long the ban remains. Your specific occurance is more nuanced, though.

Comment: @Spevacus, thank you for the link. I searched for the place to fill bugs and was directed here(meta.SE) so I missed it at meta.SO. And there is a funny thing about my particular ban indeed. I did not decided yet whether I want to spend my time on disputing it - I will probably let it go.

Comment: @Tom, It looks like I did not search long enough before asking my question. Thanks to Spevacus I found several similar questions at meta.SO. I believe that my question is dupe indeed, it has no valuable information and thus can be deleted.